# snake game in pygame doesn't run

Tags: python, pygame

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

class Snake:
    def __init__(self, parent_screen):
        self.parent_screen = parent_screen
        self.block = pygame.image.load("BLOCK.png")
        self.x = 100
        self.y = 100
    
    def draw(self):
        self.parent_screen.fill("White")
        self.parent_screen.blit(self.block, (self.x,self.y))
        pygame.display.flip()

    def move_up(self):
        self.y -= 10
        self.draw()

    def move_down(self):
        self.y += 10
        self.draw()

    def move_right(self):
        self.x += 10
        self.draw()

    def move_left(self):
        self.x -= 10
        self.draw()    

class game:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
        self.screen.fill("White")
        self.snake = Snake(self.screen)
        self.snake.draw()
        

    def run(self):
        game_on = True

        while game_on:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_w:
                        self.snake.move_up()

                    elif event.key == K_s:
                        self.snake.move_down()

                    elif event.key == K_a:
                        self.snake.move_left()

                    elif event.key == K_d:
                        self.snake.move_right()

                elif event.type == QUIT:
                    game_on = False
                
                pygame.display.flip()


Game = game()
Game.run
```

Comment: What is not working? Please find a better title for your question. The explanation  belongs to the body not to the title. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: sorry its my first time using stackoverflow and i thought body is just for code, but thanks im going to edit it

Comment: Typo: `Game.run()` instead of `Game.run`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scene must be draw and updated in the application:

```py
class game:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
        #self.screen.fill("White")                       # <-- DELETE
        self.snake = Snake(self.screen)
        #self.snake.draw()                               # <-- DELETE 
        
    def run(self):
        game_on = True
        while game_on:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_w:
                        self.snake.move_up()
                    elif event.key == K_s:
                        self.snake.move_down()
                    elif event.key == K_a:
                        self.snake.move_left()
                    elif event.key == K_d:
                        self.snake.move_right()

                elif event.type == QUIT:
                    game_on = False

            self.screen.fill("White")                   # <-- INSERT
            self.snake.draw()                           # <-- INSERT
            pygame.display.flip() 

Game = game()
Game.run()                                              # <-- ()
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)